# Related Articles list is not visible for guest user

Tags: community, lightning, lightning-experience, napili

I am using Related Articles list component in Napili community. It is visible only for logged user. The component is not visible for not-logged-in user.

Edit: Also, the issue seems to be with Trending Articles, Trending articles shown to logged in user are different from what it is showing to Guest user.

Guest user has Read Access to all article types.

Comment: Check the permissions on the guest profile and have you set up the topics for the knowledge articles?

Comment: Yes, the guest profile has read access to all article types. And i have setup topics also.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue and came to know there are two known issues with workaround:

**KNOWN ISSUE 1:**

[Related Articles List component causes ISE (2003004817) for guest users in community when "Give access to public API requests on Chatter" is disabled](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008gXBQAY&title=causes-ise-2003004817-for-guest-users-in-community-when-give-access-to-public-api-requests-on-chatter-is-disabled)

WORKAROUND as per given in this page:

> Select the "Give access to public API requests on Chatter" setting via
>   Community Management | Administration | Preferences or remove the
>   Related Articles List Lightning Component from the Article detail page
>   in your community.

**KNOWN ISSUE 2:**

[Related Articles List in a Community will not show for guest user if user language does not match site context language](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000018BSHQA2&title=related-articles-list-in-a-community-will-not-show-for-guest-user-if-user-language-does-not-match-site-context-language)

WORKAROUND as per given in this page:

> No Suggested Workaorund currently to get related articles on language
>   that does not match user language.
>
> Suggestion is:  Create a parallel community for each language you plan
>   on supporting and route the guest user to the correct community based
>   on their language choice.